# How does pandas argsort work? How do I interpret the result?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas series:

```
>>>ser
num  let
0    a      12
     b      11
     c      18
1    a      10
     b       8
     c       5
2    a       8
     b       9
     c       6
3    a      15
     b      10
     c      11
```

When I use argsort, I get this:

```
>>>ser.argsort()
num  let
0    a       5
     b       8
     c       4
1    a       6
     b       7
     c       3
2    a      10
     b       1
     c      11
3    a       0
     b       9
     c       2
```

Which I don't really understand. Shouldn't ser[(1, 'c')] get the lowest value from argsort?

I am further confused by how ordering ser according to ser.argsort() works like a charm:

```
>>>ser.iloc[ser.argsort()]
num  let
1    c       5
2    c       6
1    b       8
2    a       8
     b       9
1    a      10
3    b      10
0    b      11
3    c      11
0    a      12
3    a      15
0    c      18
```

Will appreciate any input to help me sort this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not how `argsort` works. `argsort` tells you where that element comes from in the original list. If you look at the `argsort`ed index, you see the first element belongs to index 5 in the original series. If you look at the 5th index, you'll see that's `5`, which is indeed the smallest value. And so on.

Answer (score 3):

Per the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.argsort.html

`pd.Series.argsort()`

does the same job as `np.ndarray.argsort()`, namely (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html#numpy-argsort)

"Returns the indices that would sort an array."

So it returns the Series with the values replaced by the order the index should be in to see the Series sorted. This is why when you call `ser.iloc[ser.argsort()]`, you get a sorted Series.

If you're looking for a simple way to sort the series by values, why not just use `ser.sort_values()`?

The confusion over what `ser.argsort()[(1, 'c')]` returns is understandable.

You might expect it to return the position of `ser[(1,'c')]` after the sort, but that's not what it's trying to do.

What `ser.argsort()[(1, 'c')]` is doing is:

- once we've performed the argsort, what is old the *positional* index of the value which now resides at the *location* index (1,'c').
- After sorting the series, the value which would sit where (1,'c') was previously is (1,'b'), which is ser.iloc[3], hence you get 3.

It's not at all intuitive, but that's what it is!

`argsort` returns a series with the same index as the initial series (so you can use .iloc as you have), but with the values replaced by the prior position of the sorted value.

Comment: This really doesn't answer my question. Since `min(ser) = ser[(1, 'c')] = 5`, I'd expect `ser.argsort()[(1, 'c')]` to equal 0 (i.e be the first value in the sorted series).

Comment: Have added a bit of explanation, but I think COLDSPEED has covered it a bit more concisely than I have!

Comment: Indeed. I was confused by the fact the `ser.argsort()` returns the original indices, which is quite unfortunate in my opinion :)

Comment: It is confusing, and I'm struggling to see the utility of the method, but I'm sure there is one. Potentially speeds up sorting on very large Series objects? https://imgur.com/a/yVRIw

Comment: I think it's mostly good for sorting one series, according to another series. I don't think it's faster than `ser.sort_values()`

Comment: I think pandas would be better to remove the indices from the output, since they only create confusion.